# Access the main OMNET++ simulation thread from a working/child thread

Tags: multithreading, omnet++

I wrote a simple multi-threaded application in OMNET++ that does not call any OMNET++ API in the working thread and is working as expected. I know that OMNET++ does not support multi-thread applications by design, but I was wondering if there is any mechanism that I can use to make a bridge between my worker thread and my code in the main simulation thread.

More specifically, I am saving some data in a vector in the working thread and I want to signal the code in the simulation thread to consume it (producer/consumer scenario). Is there any way to achieve this?

Do I need to design my own event scheduler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**METHOD 1**
The simplest way to achieve your goal is to use a selfmessage in simulation thread and a small modification of worker thread. The worker thread should modify a common variable (visible by both threads). And the selfmessage should periodically check the state of this variable.

The sample code of this idea:

```
// common variable
bool vectorReady; 

// worker thread
if (someCondition) {
    vectorReady = true;
}

// simulation thread
void someclass::handleMessage(cMessage * msg) {
   if (msg->isSelfMessage()) {
       if (vectorReady) {
          vectorReady = false;
          // reads vector data 
       }
       scheduleAt(simTime() + somePeriod, msg);
   }
```

The place of declaration of common variable depends how you create and start the worker thread.

**METHOD 2**
The other way is to create own scheduler and adding a condition just before every event. By default `OMNeT++` uses `cSequentialScheduler` scheduler. It has the method `takeNextEvent()` which is called to obtain next event. You can create a derived class and overwrite this method, for example:

```
// cThreadScheduler.h
#include <omnetpp.h>
using namespace omnetpp;

class cThreadScheduler : public cSequentialScheduler {
public:
    virtual cEvent *takeNextEvent() override;
};

// cThreadScheduler.cc
#include "cThreadScheduler.h"
Register_Class(cThreadScheduler);

cEvent* cThreadScheduler::takeNextEvent() {
   if (vectorReady) {
      vectorReady = false;
      // reads vector data 
   }
   return cSequentialScheduler::takeNextEvent();
}
```

In `omnetpp.ini` add a line:

```
scheduler-class = "cThreadScheduler"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am doing the exact same thing in my code. But since I am looking for a close to real-time performance, the above approach does not work for me. That's why I am looking for a way to send a signal to the simulation thread notifying it that a data is ready in the buffer. Polling the shared vector, similar to your approach, is not what I am looking for.

Comment: I am thinking of a way to modify the OMNET++ event scheduler so that it checks the shared vector before scheduling the next pending event. Is there any way/tutorial to do this?

Comment: I have edited my answer and added a sample code for own scheduler.